# Dynamic Host name in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, iis

How can I dynamically create a host name in ASP.NET? Like if people come to my site, I want to be able to dynamically create them a .Mysite.Com host name. I've seen this done at other sites before but can't seem to find documation on how to do it. Any help would be appreciated. I'm using VB.NET/ASP.NET 2008 and IIS 6.0

Comment: Guys, thanks for the replies, but I don't want to have to do it through IIS. I want to be able to automate it through a C# or VB.NET program. Like if you go to http://www.clockspot.net and sign up for an account, and hit the submit button, the site immediately gives you a <username>.clockspot.net URL. This is what I'm trying to accomplish

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Configure the authoritative DNS to resolve any subdomain to the same IP address
2. Configure the web server at IP address to serve the same web site for any subdomain
3. Use the HTTP_HOST environment variable to get the DNS name:

```
Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_HOST"]
```

Comment: CNAME record in DNS can you set like: 

name: "*.Mysite.Com" ttl: "86400"  value: "Mysite.Com."

Comment: Guys, thanks for the replies, but I don't want to have to do it through IIS. I want to be able to automate it through a C# or VB.NET program. Like if you go to http://www.clockspot.net and sign up for an account, and hit the submit button, the site immediately gives you a <username>.clockspot.net URL. This is what I'm trying to accomplish

Comment: In step 3, check if `HTTP_HOST` is in your username database and return an error page if it doesn't. It seems that's exactly what clockspot does: http://doesnotexist.clockspot.net/